# Need to understand this python code

Tags: python

Having problems understanding 2 things in the code below.
Problem 1: I dont understand what is themap and what is it's use.
Usually when we create functions with 2 arguments like here :

`def find_city(themap,state):` shouldn't we enter the value of the 2 arguments
`themap` and `state` when we run the program? And yet, we only give the values of state
i.e we enter either CA OR MI OR FL . I dont understand what is `themap` being used for.

Problem 2 : I dont understand the line `cities['_find'] = find_city`
I searched google for `'_find' python` and the only thing I found was reference to zed shaw's book. which category does it come under or what should I read to learn more about this line?

```
cities = {'CA': 'San Francisco', 'MI': 'Detroit',
                     'FL': 'Jacksonville'}

cities['NY'] = 'New York'
cities['OR'] = 'Portland'

def find_city(themap, state):
    if state in themap:
        return themap[state]
    else:
        return "Not found."

# ok pay attention!
cities['_find'] = find_city

while True:
    print "State? (ENTER to quit)",
    state = raw_input("> ")

    if not state: break

    # this line is the most important ever! study!
    city_found = cities['_find'](cities, state)
    print city_found
```

EDIT: Could you also tell me which chapter or python topic should I study to be able to understand this better. I mean, to better understand about the questions that I asked.

Comment: `cities['_find'] = find_city` is way to reference find_city function, hence this dictionary element is a function, to call it just reference the element then add arguments: `cities['_find'](cities, state)`, it's just another way to call find_city function.

Comment: **Problem 1:** The value of `themap` comes from the function call: `city_found = cities['_find'](cities, state)`, i.e. the dictionary `cities` is passed as the first argument of `find_city` method and copies into `themap`, so no need to take `themap` from user. **Problem 2:** `'_find'` here is not a keyword and has been used just as an indexing value for the `dict` object **`cities`**... it could have been anything (e.g. `'find'`, `'_search'`, `'locate'` etc).

Comment: `cities['_find'] = find_city` is a terrible idea. Now if someone tried to find a city called `"_find"` they will be returned a function instead of the message `"Not found."`

Answer (score 5):

this line

```
city_found = cities['_find'](cities, state)
```

is calling

```
def find_city(themap, state):
```

therefore

```
themap ==> cities
state ==> state
```

Answer (score 2):

When the call is made to to `find_city` (note the previous assignment of `cities['_find'] = find_city`)

```
city_found = cities['_find'](cities, state)
```

you are sending the
dictionary `cities` along with the `state`. The identifier `cities`
gets re-mapped (renamed if you like) to `themap` in the function, `state` stays the same in this part of the code:

```
def find_city(themap, state)
```

I.e., in your "main program" the you refer to the dictionary as `cities` but when you make the call to the function, the function refers to it as `themap`. `state` stays the same. Names are matched by position between the identifiers in the call and those listed in the function header.

`cities[_find]` allows you to index into the `cities` dictionary using
`state` in the `find_city` function.

Reading more about functions and the parameter passing mechanism, function assignments (to variables) and dictionaries in Python should help solidify your understanding of this type of code constructs. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

> def find_city(themap,state): shouldn't we enter the value of the 2 arguments themap and state when we run the program?

No; we should **pass** two arguments to the function *when we call the function*.

Not every piece of data a program works with has to come from the user. It can supply its own data, read things from files, etc.

> I dont understand the line cities['_find'] = find_city

`cities` is a dictionary. So `cities[<anything in here>] = <anything over there>` puts the `<anything over there>` value into the dictionary with the key `<anything over here>`. Here our key is the string `'_find'`, and the value is the function `find_city`. Yes, in Python, everything is an object, and that includes functions. So we can certainly store functions in a container :)

```
city_found = cities['_find'](cities, state)
```

Here, we evaluate `cities['_find']` - i.e., we look up the key `'_find'` in the dictionary `cities`, finding the function `find_city`; then we use that result with `(cities, state)`. Thus it is the same as if we had written `find_city(cities, state)`; that's a normal function call. `state` is the value that the user input, which gets passed as `state`; and `cities` is the dictionary, which gets passed as `themap`. Inside the function, the named state is looked up in the `cities` dictionary.

Comment: hmm, okay so why was it written like cities['_find'] and not find_city(cities, state) ? what was the advantage in writing it like cities['_find'] ?

Comment: @faraz Good question, I am not sure I see any advantage in this either, in fact it seems only to obfuscate the code unnecessarily. Or can anyone think of a good reason to do this here?

Comment: could you also tell me which topic of python should I read about to make better sense of these problems I talked about?

Comment: @faraz I would probably spend some time reading about the function calling process (ie how arguments/parameters are mapped) and then also look for and read up about function assignments (to variables) - hope that helps get you started.

Comment: hmm, okay. could you tell me what you mean by " and cities is the dictionary, which gets passed as themap " oops. I just noticed this statement was written by Karl. But still, could Karl or anyone explain this.

Comment: @faraz Actually, I wrote something quite similar. I added a bit more explanation to my answer below about this. Reading about functions and parameters will also help make this clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
city_found = cities['_find'](cities, state)
```

Here you have used a calling function, and this calls the pre defined function DEF ---
it calls 'themap' for cities
and 'state' for state

But problem still remain is that why to use '_' sign before 'find'...
thank you.

Comment: Good question. I was curious about this too.
I was reading about python identifiers and found that this is a python identifier. 
An identifier starts with a letter A to Z or a to z or an underscore (_) followed by zero or more letters, underscores, and digits (0 to 9. 
This should make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Themap is not map in the sense of a map of cities in a geographical sense. Python maps are a data type. It's clear the function is being passed a container with cities and that in the function it's passing a city to be looked up within the container. Maybe you're really novice-in the context of a function, a parameter takes on a different name, but has the same value at the top of the function.

In python everything has a value that can be assigned, even functions. The problem 2 you're asking about is just a new name for the same function.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you are right - find_city accepts two arguments, and that how many it's given when it's called, namely

   cities['_find'](cities, state)
2. This just means that an entry is added to the cities map. The key for the entry is the string "_find" and the value is the finction find_city.
   That's why the expression cities['_find'] returns the function and then you call it with two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `themap` is a so called map or dictionary or hash-based **container**. It is used just like an array because the `operator[]` is overloaded somehow (I come from C++ background, and it is doable in C++). When you assign `'New York'` to `cities['NY']` the key 'NY' is created automatically and the value corresponding to that key is 'New York'.

To answer your second question, `find_city` is a **function pointer** of some sort which is paired with the key `'_find'`. Here `_find` is an arbitrary choice of key. You could have used `find` or `Find` or anything else you wanted. No wonder you did not find anything about it on Google. The line `cities['_find'](cities, state)` actually internally gets translated to `find_city(cities, state)`.

Hope I have helped a bit, :).

Comment: It isn't really "operator overloading"; that functionality is built-in. But for what it's worth, in Python you make it possible to use subscripting (what C++ programmers charmingly call "operator[]") by providing the magic `__getitem__` and/or `__getslice__` methods for a class.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Then it's kind of like PHP and not C++, my mistake. Thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are values you can pass around.

Saying `cities['_find']` is equivalent to saying `find_city`, since they both evaluate to that function.
    fn = cities['_find']
    fn(cities, state)

In python, function call syntax applied to a value tries to call that value with the arguments, if it is callable. So in your case, `cities['_find'].__call__(cities, state)` ends up being executed.

Answer (score -1):

You just look at two lines from your code:

1. `cities['_find'] = find_city`
2. `city_found = cities['find'](cities, state)`

#### Explanation for (1):

As cities is dictionary before you use `cities['_find']`.
print it...

```
print(cities)
Output: {'CA': 'San Francisco', 'MI': 'Detroit', 'FL': 'Jacksonville', 'NY': 'New York', 'OR': 'Portland'}
```

Now after using `cities['_find']=find_city`,

```
print(cities)  
Output: {'CA': 'San Francisco', 'MI': 'Detroit', 'FL': 'Jacksonville', 'NY': 'New York', 'OR': 'Portland', *'_find': <function find_city at 0x01BAB738*>}
```

Here the last dictionary item is added with key `_find` and the value is the function `find_city`.

#### Explanation for (2):

Now `city_found = cities['find'](cities, state)`

Now we know that find_city is in the dict at `_find`, that means we can do work with it. The it can be broken down like this:

1. Python sees `city_found =` and knows we want to make a new variable.
2. It then reads cities and finds that variable, it’s a dict.
3. Then there’s `['_find']` which will index into the cities dict and pull out whatever is at `_find`.
4. What is at `['_find']` is our function `find_city` so Python then knows it’s got a function, and it does the function call.
5. The parameters cities, state are passed to this function `find_city`, and it runs because it’s called.
6. `find_city` then tries to look up states inside cities, and returns what it finds.
7. Python takes what `find_city` returned, and finally that is what is assigned to `city_found`.